# Get widget data attribute in Gridster

Tags: jquery

I want to get the data attributes per widget in gridster.js.

```
draggable: {
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        var positions = JSON.stringify(this.serialize());
        var att = $(".gridster ul li").attr('data-id');
        alert(att);
        //localStorage.setItem('positions', positions);
        //console.log(positions);
        $.ajax ({
          url: '/partA-save-widgets-positions',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            'positions': positions
          },
          dataType: 'JSON',
          error: function(log) {
            console.log(log);
          },
          success: function(log) {
            console.log(log);
          }
        })
      }
```

html

```
<div class="gridster">
   <ul>
      @foreach($widgets as $wi)
      <li data-row="2" data-id="7">values</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
 </div>
```

using

```
 var att = $(".gridster ul li").attr('data-id');
    alert(att); //undefined
```

Comment: What is `this` here? where are you actually calling this `$(this).attr('data-row')` code?

Comment: I am trying to get data-id and data-row on a specific li during if I drag the widget

Comment: partA:957 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: what are you getting for `console.log(ui)`?

Comment: @palasH  Object (Object {position: Object, pointer: Object, $player: n.fn.init[1], $helper: n.fn.init[1]})

Comment: and `console.log(ui.$helper)` & `console.log($(ui.$helper))`?

Comment: li.gs-w.player-revert, context: li.gs-w.player-revert]  li.gs-w.player-revert, selector: "", context: li.gs-w.player-revert]

Comment: Ok, then try: `var att = $(ui.$helper).attr('data-id');` and `var att2 = $(ui.$helper).attr('data-row');` once? What are you getting now?

Comment: var att = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-row');  works.. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ui` variable here to achieve this like:-

```
var att = $(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-row'); 
alert(att);
```

As a suggestion, you can always debug the code yourself using the `console.log()` and checking what the `ui` variable is actually pointing to and debug more to find the object properties it have and then find that current element being dragged, as we have discussed in the comments above like:

```
draggable: {
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui);  // check the properties here
    console.log(ui.$helper);  // check other properties inside ui
    console.log($(ui.$helper[0]).attr('data-id'));  // final required value
  }
}
```

Hope this helps the furture users having the same issue while using `draggable` or any other `jquery ui` widgets!